# Submitting multiples values through single checkbox using Angular 2 reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm looking for the best way to submit multiple values through a single checkbox. The values are are being saved in a service.

Using the attribute syntax I can bind to an additional `data-*` property. Is there a way to consolidate the the values of the custom `data-*` and `value` attributes to send together on 'submission' or should this be approached differently using the `getAttribute()` method?

**Template**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
    <template ngFor let-stock [ngForOf]="availableStock">
                <p><label><input type="radio" formControlName="size" [value]="stock.size" [attr.data-stock-sku]="stock.sku" [id]="stock.size">{{ stock.size }}</label></p>  
    </template>

    <p><button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactive-form',
  templateUrl: './reactive-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reactive-form.component.css']
})

export class ReactiveFormComponent implements OnInit {
    public myForm: FormGroup;
    public availableStock: Array<{"size": string, "sku": string}> = [{"size": "36", "sku": "5409756"}, {"size": "38", "sku": "5409750"},{"size": "40", "sku": "5409754"}];

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.createForm();
    }

    createForm(){
        this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            size: [ null , Validators.required  ]
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onSubmit() {
        if(this.myForm.valid) {
            // submit form eg this._formService.saveFormValues(this.myForm.value);
        } else {
            // display errors
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: For clarity, I would like to submit/save multiple values which are assigned to a single checkbox. These are the values assigned to the 'value' attribute and the data-stock-sku/attr.data-stock-sku attribute in the HTML. However on submission Angular only sends through the value assigned to the 'value' attribute by default.

Comment: You mean you want to submit the form when the `checkbox` is ticked?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't too clear. I would like to submit/save multiple values which are assigned to a single checkbox. These are the values assigned to the 'value' attribute and the data-stock-sku/attr.data-stock-sku attribute in the HTML. However on submission Angular only sends through the value assigned to the 'value' attribute by default. Hopefully these clears things up

Comment: Ah I see. I would suggest that since you are using reactive forms, you can build another form that stores your `stock` object (and you do not need to display them in your html. Then, you can subscribe to your checkbox value, and decide what to do with your `stock` form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use the size as an unique ID, I would rather retrieve data then send it, rather than assigning several values to an HTML component (that is supposed to handle strings)

```
onSubmit() {
    if(this.myForm.valid) {
        let userSelectedValue = this.availableStock.find(stock => stock.size === this.myForm.get('size').value);
        // Use your value here 
    } else {
        // Handle your errors yourself
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, trichetriche. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you had in mind but your answer def. pointed me in the right direction. I've created an addition formControl name `sku` which is hidden from the HTML template. And the value assigned right before 'submission'.`this.availableStock.filter((element) => { if(element.size == this.myForm.get('size').value) { this.myForm.get("sku").setValue(element.sku) } })` ... of course I welcome any feedback

Comment: This is ... Absolutely not what I meant. I strongly dislike your method, I've never used hidden fields in my life and I really dont' like it. But it's totally personal, and as they say, "whatever floats your boat" ! Anyway, I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: Right. I've misunderstood. Could you clarify at all?

Comment: What should I clarify ? Why I do think that ?

Comment: More your answer as I had misunderstood it. But nevermind, I think i know understand

Comment: Oh okay, all I was saying is that you should go through your array to find the corresponding `sku` of the `size` the user selected.